# how can I predict the rate of water ions precipitation on a surface?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, ions, precipitation, water-treatment

Consider a titanium pot that contains 1kg water with the following ions:

$[Ca^{2+}]=22000$ ppm, $[Mg^{2+}]=1500$ ppm,$[Sr^{2+}]=791$ ppm,$[Na^{1+}]=48000$ ppm,$[Cl^{1-}]=120000$ ppm,$[SO_4^{2-}]=22000$ ppm

And predict the rate of component precipitation like CaSO4, CaCl2 and ... on the inside wall of the titanium surface at the 20 C, 30C, 50C.

Calculate the rate of component precipitation in water not only on the titanium wall.

After that, calculate the final steady-state ion contents that exists in the water.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. Could you describe the system you are looking at? Which surface, what do you mean when you say "water ions", what do you mean by "precipitation on a surface", and what do you mean by "saturation state of that compound"? It would be great if you could edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: I have edited my question